# Find source of get request in chrome debugger

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have an odd request showing up in a Vue application, and I'm trying to trace down the source of it.

If I look at the network tab in the debugger, it indicates the Initiator as `vue.runtime.esm.js:6613` which is internal vue stuff.  I'm guessing it's some sort of node library that's calling this initially, but I can't find out where it's coming from.

I ran a grep on my client directory for `nighthawk.ca` (and also for DateAndTimeScreenShot.gif) figuring it'd pull up a node_modules lib, but neither returned any results.  Scrolling down through the console's GET request callstack shows nothing out of the ordinary.

Where else can I look for clues on how request file is being introduced?

[image]

Comment: You can set a conditional breakpoint in `Watcher` and see which property/expression triggers it.

Comment: @wOxxOm - any chance you can point me to a reference?  I'm not seeing anything about how to add a watch for network requests, and not sure how I'd go about capturing that with a conditional.  Thanks

Comment: `Watcher` is a function in the initiator call stack. Click it to open the devtools debugger.

Comment: @wOxxOm - I found that, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to utilize it.  How would I know what expression to use to break on?  I can set a non-conditional and continue for each time it's hit, but when it hits the bad request my callstack goes away and it stops executing, so I can't quite catch it.  I suppose I could count the number of times I have to continue until it happens and back up one manually, unless there's an easier way?

Comment: Maybe something below `Watcher` (or above) in the call stack would be more obvious. The idea is that Vue calculates the expression so you can set a breakpoint and inspect other stuff in the context when this property is being resolved. To find the exact condition you may first try setting a logging breakpoint for some internal value in that function, then inspect the output in console that hopefully will contain that url.